# AppleScript sequential file process

Tags: applescript

I cannot work out what I am missing: the script shown is meant to process 1 or many files when file/s added to folder. However, will only process one file at a time. I.e. if 3 files are added it will only process first file. I cannot work out what I am missing and because this is running on old PPC (AS ver 2.2) cannot find much of help.

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    
    repeat with EachItem in added_items
        set ItemInfo to info for EachItem
        tell application "VectorWorks"
            activate
            open EachItem
            tell application "QuicKeys"
                play shortcut "2 Convert to VW Ver2"
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
    
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: Long long time since I used it [maybe 10 years], but you ought to be able to get QuicKeys itself to do that loop, without needing the script.

Comment: I thought that too but not a coder. First bit is how to watch a folder, not sure how to do that, second is how to loop round, I figure that I need to use variables somewhere as a counter but that's about it. But given your comments will take another look at the manual to see if I can glean anything from there. Thanks for responding.